# Grading Answers during a Self-Study

Tags: grading, independent-study

I have recently begun self-studying *Complex Variables An Introduction* by Dr. Berenstein and Dr. Gay from the Springer-Verlag series in graduate maths. Unlike my experience with undergraduate texts, the manuscript, unfortunately, does not contain an answer key. Without a teaching assistant to grade my work, I am largely at a loss about grading my work for the more sophisticated questions.

I have already posted a sampling of problems on Mathematics StackExchange; however, no one has answered them.

**Question:** Is there a service where I could hire somebody to grade my work?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have you tried googling to see if the solutions exist online? Asking your supervisor or university librarian? You could even email the authors to ask for it.

Comment: If you have access to a university library, it might help to check out several of the many complex analysis texts at the same level for supplementary reading and text-worked examples and problems and problem solutions. If not, or even in addition, perhaps obtain a copy of [**Schaum's Outline of Complex Variables**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0071615695) and refer to it for specific topics you have difficulty with. *(Moments later)* Oh, I just googled this book (one I am not familiar with) and see it's at a much higher level than the Schaum's Outline. My first suggestion still applies, however.

Comment: So far, I've tried Google, Bing, and others to no avail. Although the book is ~30 years old, it appears that no one has made a public answer key available. A while back, I was able to find an answer key and solutions manual to Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds from the Caltech Electrical Engineering Department. Do you know of any keywords that would be helpful in a search?

Comment: Googling ["Complex Variables" + "Berenstein" + "Gay" + "solutions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Complex+Variables%22+%22Berenstein%22+%22Gay%22+%22solutions%22) (note quotes used) led me to [this course blog with some solutions](https://caicedoteaching.wordpress.com/previous-courses/complex-analysis-uc-berkeley-summer-2002/).

Comment: If such a service existed, and was affordable and of adequate quality, I suspect it would quickly be swamped with demand from universities looking to contract out some of their own grading activities.